# Is there any advantage of keeping a property non observable vs observable in knockout js?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I am using typescript to write knockout js. I have a class with multiple properties. I have a 'description' property which is not connected to DOM but needs to be used on some popups on some mouse event (button click). I can easily access that property and display a popup but is there any advantage/disadvantage of using the 'description' property as knockout observable vs non observable?

Comment: Depends on how what this click event does and where exactly you use `description`. If you're not using this `description` in any `data-bind` in your HTML or any `computed` property, there is no need to make it an observable.

Comment: Showing it in HTML through a binding works just fine whether it's observable or not. The difference is it won't automatically update when its value changes if it's not an observable - it will update if the binding is recreated though (like if the element is removed from the DOM and re-added by a parent binding, for instance).

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to clarify if there are any other advantages for not making it observable e.g. performance. If yes. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can KO know when parts of your view model change?**
>
> Answer: you need to declare your model properties as observables,
>   because these are special JavaScript objects that can notify
>   subscribers about changes, and can automatically detect dependencies.

If you wanted to show the updated description value in your popup, or wanted to do *something* on when the description property is been changed, then it has to be defined as `observable`.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on whether your `description` property is static or dynamic. If it's not going to change then it shouldn't be observable. If it is going to change then it needs to be for the changes to be reflected in your pop-up (and any `computed` properties that might refer to it).